# Solve $z^4+2z^3+3z^2+2z+1 =0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve $z^4+2z^3+3z^2+2z+1 =0$ with $z$: a complex variable.

**Attempt at solving the problem**:

We divide the polynom by $z^2$ and we get:

$z^2+2z+3+\dfrac{2}{z}+  \dfrac{1}{z^2}=0  $  $         $ We set $w=z+  \dfrac{1}{z}$

We now have $w^2+2w+5=0$

$\bigtriangleup = -16$

Let's find $\omega$ such that $\omega^2=-16$

We have $\omega=4i$
Therefore we have the 2 roots:
$w_    {1}=-1-2i$ and $ w_    {2}=-1+2i  $

**The issue is: I don't know how to find z**

Comment: $z^2-wz+1=0$. -

Comment: Once you found the possible values for $w$ then just substitute them back into $w=z+\tfrac1z$ and solve for $z$. By the way you already did the hard part, which was to recognize that the polynomial in question is symmetric, and to use the substitution $w=z+\tfrac1z$.

Comment: Where is $\bigtriangleup = -16$ coming from? Solving $w^2 + 2w + 5 = 0$ gives $w = -1 \pm 2i$.

Comment: @DylanSp it is the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ from the quadratic equation.

Comment: @Clayton Ah, hadn't seen that notation before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^4+2z^2+3z^2+2z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(z^2+z+1\right)^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2+z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2+z=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2+z+\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z+\frac{1}{2}=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: How do i solve it using the change of complex variable?

Answer (score 0):

> "I don't know how to find z"

Sure you do!

....

If you are correct in what you have done so far and you have

$z + \frac 1z = w$

And $w_1 = -1-2i$ and $w_2 = -1 + 2i$ then

you need to solve $z +\frac 1z = (-1-2i)$ or $z^2 +(1+2i)z + 1=0$

ANd $z + \frac 1z = (-1+2i)$ or $z^2 + (1-2i)z + 1 = 0$.

Both of which can be solved by quadratic equation to get the four solutions

$z = \frac {(-1\pm 2i) \pm\sqrt{(1\mp 2i)^2 -4}}{2}$

(And if you are worried about expressing $\sqrt{M}$ just convert to polar coordinates.)

That is.... if everything you've done is correct.